# Can Remote Desktop app on OS X restore sessions after sleep or WiFi outage?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

On Windows, when I have a Remote Desktop connection active, and the WiFi disconnects temporarily / or the laptop goes to sleep, the Remote Desktop sessions are restored automatically and seamlessly (very convenient).

On MAC OS X (Yosemite) on the other hand, whenever the WiFi breaks, or when the laptop goes to stand-by/sleep, the Remote Desktop session is simply dropped and I have to reconnect and re-log in.

Is it possible to set up the same behaviour as in Windows, so that the Remote Desktop app reconnects automatically as from the previous state?

I'm using the native Remote Desktop App made by Microsoft from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not :( - the Mac OSX Remote Desktop client does not support "autoreconnect" - "autoreconnect" is a feature that (I think) all the other Microsoft Remote Desktop clients that allows them that after the connection gets abruptly interrupted (e.g.: WiFi drops, machine sleep) to recover the connection.

This is a highly desired feature and the team is looking into providing a fix (I work on the Remote Desktop team at MSFT, but not on the Mac OSX client).

/cd